# Lower bound for norm of sum of vectors

Tags: integration, vectors, absolute-value

It is common to use:
$$\| \sum_{i=1}^n \bar X_i \| \le \sum_{i=1}^n \|\bar X_i \|. $$

Now for 2 dimensions, I know that:

$$ \|\bar A + \bar B \|^2 = (\bar A + \bar B)\cdot(\bar A + \bar B)$$
$$ = \bar A \cdot \bar A + 2 \bar A \cdot \bar B + \bar B \cdot \bar B $$
$$ = \|\bar A\|^2 + \|\bar B\|^2 + 2 \bar A \cdot \bar B $$

and since $\bar A \cdot \bar B = \|\bar A\| \|\bar B\|\ cos\ \theta \ge -\|\bar A\| \|\bar B\|:$

$$ \|\bar A + \bar B\|^2 \ge \|\bar A\|^2 + \|\bar B\|^2 - 2\|\bar A\|\|\bar B|| $$
$$ = \left(\|\bar A\| - \|\bar B\|\right)^2 $$
$$ \rightarrow \|\bar A + \bar B\| \ge \|\bar A\| - \|\bar B\|, $$

which gives a lower bound for $ \|\bar A + \bar B\|. $

I have tried to generalize this approach for more dimensions, but the best I got was:

$$ \Vert \bar A + \bar B + \bar C \Vert^2 = \left( \bar A + \bar B + \bar C \right) \cdot \left( \bar A + \bar B + \bar C \right) $$
$$ = \bar A \cdot \bar A + \bar B \cdot \bar B + \bar C \cdot \bar C + 2\left( \bar A \cdot \bar B + \bar B \cdot \bar C + \bar A \cdot \bar C \right) $$
$$ \ge \Vert \bar A \Vert^2 + \Vert \bar B \Vert^2 + \Vert \bar C \Vert^2 - 2 \left( \Vert \bar A \Vert \Vert \bar B \Vert + \Vert \bar B \Vert \Vert \bar C \Vert + \Vert \bar A \Vert \bar C \Vert \right) $$
$$ = \left( \Vert \bar A \Vert^2 - 2\Vert \bar A \Vert \Vert \bar B \Vert + \Vert \bar B \Vert^2 \right) + \Vert \bar C \Vert^2 - 2 \left( \Vert \bar A \Vert \Vert \bar C \Vert + \Vert \bar B \Vert \Vert \bar C \Vert \right) $$
$$ = \left( \Vert \bar A \Vert - \Vert \bar B \Vert \right)^2 + \Vert \bar C \Vert^2 - 2\Vert \bar C \Vert \left( \Vert \bar A \Vert + \Vert \bar B \Vert \right) $$

which doesn't seem very useful.

Is there a lower bound for the magnitude of the sum of $n$ vectors? (other than $0$, of course). How should I go about proving it?

Actually this question came up when I was trying to find a lower bound for $\left|\int_{-\infty}^t x(\tau) \, d\tau\right|.$ I realize I have gone astray from the original problem, but still both questions interest me. I would appreciate any help, and thanks for reading through whoever does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The natural generalization is 
$$ \left\|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right\| \ge \|X_1\| - \sum_{i=2}^n \|X_i\|$$

which follows easily from the Triangle Inequality.

Comment: It took a while but I wrapped my head around this result. Do you know of any book I could check out to look further into this kind of bound? And thank you for the answer

Comment: How do you chose $X_1$ to maximize the bound? For example if we chose the set of 1D vector (which I will denote as scalars), for ${1,-4,4}$, then $1-4-4=-7$, but $4-1-4=-1$ which is a better bound. Best I can think is trying all values in the $X_1$ position -- trying to find the one that is closest to the sum of the magnitudes of the rest.

Comment: The only good $X_1$ is the element with the largest norm, and the inequality is only useful if its norm is greater than the sum of the norms of all the other vectors.

Comment: Can't we define all kinds of bounds that only work for certain $X_1$'s and are only useful under certain times? For example for $X_2$ the second largest, and $X_1$ the largest, the bound given by $\left\Vert \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\right\Vert \ge\|X_{1}\|+\|X_{2}\|-\sum_{i=3}^{n}\|X_{i}\|$, Only useful when the sum of the largest two norms are greater than the rest, (Possibly only valid when the norm of the first is greater than the norm of the second plus the rest? (still thinking))

Comment: @oxinabox: that bound would not be true.  Try the case $n=2$.

Comment: True, good point (maybe it can be fixed? take my above formula, and add the condition $\|X_2\| - \sum_{i=2}^n \|X_i\|\le0$).
 In general is the $\max(\|X_1\| - \sum_{i=2}^n \|X_i\|,\: 0)$ as good as we can do for a low bound? . I am starting to feel that determining the highest lower bound on vector is equivalent to solving the knapsack problem.

Comment: To illustrate why it is knapsack-y:
I think the general solution may be: 
$$\min_{\forall\{c_{i}:\:\forall i\in[0,n]\,c_{i}\in\{-1,1\}\}\:}\:\left|\:\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}c_{i}\left\Vert \tilde{x}_{i}\right\Vert \:\right|\le\left\Vert \sum_{i=1}^{i=n}\tilde{x}_{i}\right\Vert \le\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}\left\Vert \tilde{x}_{i}\right\Vert 
 $$

Comment: Nonsense.  For example, you can have three vectors of norm $1$ whose sum is $0$.

Comment: Indeed, for any $r_1, \ldots, r_n \ge 0$ such that no $r_i$ is greater than the sum of all the others, there are vectors $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ in $\mathbb R^2$ such that $\|x_i\| = r_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 0$.  Thus no lower bound on $\|\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\|$ that depends only on $\|x_1\|, \ldots, \|x_n\|$ can be strictly positive when none of these norms is greater than the sum of the others.